# why this code produces a blank line between the two colored line?

Tags: includegraphics

```
\documentclass[12pt,portrait]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref} %--- per i link
\usepackage{multicol} %------ per formattare pagine a più colonne
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %--- per le caselle di testo I pagina
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
%------------------------------------
\setlength\textwidth{267mm}
\setlength\paperwidth{300mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}
%-------------------------------
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}%----- uso font garamond
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%----- uso font garamond
%\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
%------ set colori del link
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

 %----- dimensione della pagina ------
 \geometry{
 a3paper,
 total={297mm,420mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 bottom=0mm,
 }


\tcbset{colback=white!5!!,colframe=red!15!white!60!,size=small,
fonttitle=\bfseries,width=0.333\textwidth,box align=top,height=7cm,nobeforeafter}

\begin{document}
%----  inserimento banner --------
    \noindent\includegraphics [height=40mm,width=267mm]{pannello_blu_corto.png}
        
        \nointerlineskip
      \noindent\includegraphics[height=10mm,width=267mm]{filo_celeste_basso.png}



\noindent
%------ I box ---------------
\nointerlineskip
   \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{bla bla bla},halign=justify]
bla bla bla bla bla
    \end{tcolorbox} %------fine I box --------
    \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{xyzxyz xyz xyz xy},halign=justify]
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
        \end{tcolorbox}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{xyzxyz xyz xyz xy},halign=justify]
xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz
    \end{tcolorbox}\\
    \begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=left,halign=left]
```

Comment: Can you please follow these steps and upgrade your question? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 Thank you

Comment: as I said in your last question you do not want `figure` here that is making two floating display inserts that are set off with vertical space and may potentially be moved (`h` is usually chanegd to `ht` also if yo do use a figure put `\centering` first not last where it only works by accident.

Comment: @David Carlisle: ok, I've erased the two \centering instruction, but I still don't understand why there is a white line in between

P.S
are you english? many years ago, Ihave been in a city named: Carlisle

Comment: @RenatoP `a figure` is a display environment it adds vertical space and moves the content to help with page breaking, there is absolutely nothing that `figure` does that you want here, simply remove it.

Comment: yes it works! now, it begin 4 or 5 mm after the start of page

Comment: @RenatoP The code you just added to your question seems to be missing the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not floats but (I assume) part of the page design, so just place them directly, not in `figure`

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\textwidth{267mm}
\setlength\paperwidth{300mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
   \includegraphics [height=40mm,width=267mm]{example-image-a}

    \nointerlineskip
    \includegraphics[height=40mm,width=267mm]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: tha's ok!..but...if I I leave the \begin{center...\end{center, I obtain a white line before the forst image and 1 after the second image.
if I erase them, the two image are well verticaly positioned, but horizontaly 10mm ahed.

Comment: @RenatoP you have a paragraph indent before the image, if you don't center (which sets the indent to zero) then you may want `\noindent\includegraphics...` in both cases.

Comment: yeesss!!! it works! (the \noindent before each \includegraphic
Thank you David

Comment: but why between the azure line and the tcolorbox  there is one white line?
https://postimg.cc/HVn3f5sd

Comment: @RenatoP  presumably in some code you have not shown you are adding space. your questions should always have complete small documents (as in this answer) that people can run to see the issue. You can use `example-image` (or `example-image-a` as here) which are generally available for tests.

Comment: Finaly found the way to share it:
https://pastebin.com/4zbpukfW

Comment: @RenatoP no , don't use external links to pastes that will expire. edit the example in your question to be a usable example that shows the problem, just paste the document inline into the code block so it starts with `\documentclass` not (as now) `\begin{figure}`

Comment: @RenatoP also as I said above use `example-image` if I try your pastebin I get `LaTeX Warning: File \`pannello_blu_corto.png' not found on input line 46.`

Comment: @RenatoP also it errors: `! You can't use \`\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.55 \nointerlineskip` after any error do not expect usable pdf output   The error is using `\noindent
%------ I box ---------------
\nointerlineskip`   nointerlineskip has to be used in vertical mode, put it before the `\noindent`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151817/discussion-between-renatop-and-david-carlisle).